# Properties of $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

It is known that this function

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{e^x-1} dx
$$

is not integrable.

But, I have a function $f(x)$ such that

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{e^x-1} dx=C<\infty
$$

(that is, $f(x)$ makes the integral convergent)
Then, can I say that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=0$$ and 
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)^2}{(e^x-1)^2} dx<\infty ?
$$

Comment: do you mean "belong to $\Bbb{Z}$" or "integrable"?

Comment: In general, for $n>0$ we have $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}dx=\Gamma(n+1)~\zeta(n+1)$$ and $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}dx=\Gamma(n+1)~\eta(n+1),$$ see [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), and [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Comment: $f(x)\sim x^\alpha$ as $x\to 0$ for any $\alpha>0$ is sufficient. Thus, the answer to your last question is "no".

Comment: You edited your question, but the answer to your last question is still no. Same example applies...